# Standard way of modifying the commerce component theme js like cart-model.js

Tags: sitecore-commerce

Is there any standard way of modifying the base theme js file instead of download the js file -> make your changes then reupload this file on CMS.
Please suggest if any thanks.

Comment: The answer you can find here: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/12430/how-to-extend-sxa-components-scripts

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this link. 'Extend a script' section.

https://doc.sitecore.com/en/developers/93/sitecore-experience-commerce/extend-storefront-themes.html

Comment: Currently while this does provide an answer to the question, it is a link only answer. When someone goes on Stack Exchange, the question "answer" should actually contain an answer. Not just a bunch of directions towards the answer. Please see this meta post for details on how to update your answer to be Stack Exchange friendly, thanks: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259